# how to get rows count of SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get total records counts of Sqlite database table when at the end of List View scrolling.But the major problem is first time getting count is accurate.When I am again scrolling at the end count is increment. Suppose I have 181 total count of record , and again scroll at the end getting count is 362 ,  again scroll getting 543 ,...724, ...905 and etc. Why not get constant value like 181.Can someone help me to solve it?

Here is my Code for getting total count of records in Constant class

```
public final class Constant
{
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static MyDbHelper dbhelper;

   public static int GetLocalPages(Context context)
    {
        dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(context);
        dbhelper.onOpen(db);

        String query = "select count(*) from ALL_Post";
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            totalRowCount += c.getInt(0);
            Log.e("11111 ", " totalRowCount = " + totalRowCount);
        }
        if(totalRowCount < 50)
        {
            num= 1 ;
            Log.e("22222 "," num=  " +  num);
        }
        if(totalRowCount > 50)
        {
            num= totalRowCount / 50;
            Log.e("33333 ", " num=  " + num);
        }
        if(totalRowCount % 50> 0)
        {
            num += 1;
            Log.e("44444 ", " num =  " + num );
        }
        return num ;
    }

 }
```

And here is my listView scrollListener Method

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            {

                lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                //Log.e("","lastInScreen="+lastInScreen);
                if(lastInScreen == totalItemCount)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Last Item." + lastInScreen , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
int values= Constant.GetLocalPages(getApplicationContext());
                    Log.e("", "values=" + values);

                    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign totalRowCount = 0;
Before calling your DB Method...

And Why do you want it on every scroll?
It is count of your DB...and will not change on scroll.
You just need to get it once.

Comment: your query is correct.
just write totalRowCount = c.getInt(0); instead of totalRowCount += c.getInt(0);

You will get constant value of rows

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how `totalRowCount` is defined. But it looks like a class variable defined and is kept incrementing every time `GetLocalPages(Context)` is called. That explains the behavior.

Comment: @jandroid: as @Yangfan said, you should check your logical when get `totalRowCount`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

just change in your code..

```
  public final class Constant
{
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static MyDbHelper dbhelper;

   public static int GetLocalPages(Context context)
    {
        dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(context);
        dbhelper.onOpen(db);
        int num =0;            

        String query = "select count(*) from ALL_Post";
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        num =c.getCount();
        return num ;
    }

 }
```

and some chenge in listener also..

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            {

                lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                //Log.e("","lastInScreen="+lastInScreen);
                if(lastInScreen == totalItemCount)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Last Item." + lastInScreen , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             int values = 0;
             values= Constant.GetLocalPages(getApplicationContext());
                    Log.e("", "values=" + values);

                    }
            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , But still getting same issue.

Comment: I think, It will work fine instead of adding previous value in adapter or you can call notifiDataSetChange(). so , please share code where are you setting value in adapter.